# Legal for company to force employees to clock in by (unpaid) lunch break?

Tags: vacation, hours, fulltime, lunch, japan

At my company the lunch break is unpaid time, as is pretty standard.

The company allows employees to either arrive late or leave early twice per pay period month, without having to use paid leave time.

"Late" is defined as after the morning start time, which can vary depending on the employee.

**Beyond that, employees will be considered "absent" if they arrive after 12:00PM.**

**The problem is that 12:00PM marks the beginning of the lunch hour, which is unpaid time.** During this time employees are free to leave the office and go to eat where they please, or eat in the office.

In other words, workers will be penalized if they show up late for the lunch break, which is supposed to be everyone's free time to do as they please. We receive no compensation for this time, so it's essentially an oppressive rule just for the sake of having a rule.

I very politely wrote to management asking about this and pointed out that paid time resumes from 1:00PM, but the answer I received was essentially:

- "Yes, arrival after 12:00PM is considered *absent* according to policy. You can use your paid vacation time to take a half-day off if you don't want to be penalized as absent." (why should I waste paid leave for a lunch hour that was supposed to be my free time anyway?) and...
- "everyone is doing this" (everyone is too much of a pushover to speak up about the abusive and nonsensical policy, and their silence is in turn being used to justify it).

**Is it legal for a company to require that employees be present for an unpaid lunch break?** The country is Japan (unsurprisingly). The position is full-time / seisha'in.

To be clear, employees can go anywhere after the start of the lunch hour, but apparently the company really cares that employees are at the company at the *beginning* of this unpaid time, almost as if to hinder our personal plans on purpose. It doesn't benefit the company in any way to require this. Nonetheless, they are totally inflexible.

(If this is not legal, what might be some advisable next steps to take?)

Comment: I think I missed something after reading a couple times, as I don't see how you would be penalized for taking the lunch break. Say your starting hour is 8am. You arrive at 7:59am and clock in (so everything good, you arrived on time). You work until 12pm, then stand up, clock "out" I suppose, and then leave to take lunch. You eat. Then you return to office at, say, 12:59pm (again in time, no problems)... so, how can you "arrive" late to your lunch break? If you clock out at 12:10 you worked 10 extra minutes, or in other words, you gifted 10 minutes of your break... mind clarifying?

Comment: *"the company really cares that employees are at the company at the beginning of this unpaid time"* - This makes sense to me, thus why I'm confused. If you checked out for lunch at 11:50am you are checking out 10 minutes early. 11:55am, still 5 minutes early. 11:59:59, technically, one second early.... 12:00 there you go, you can go out now or at 12:01 or later, but at 12:00 your 1hour lunch starts running...

Comment: Question. I guess the lunch hour is not flexible, in the way that if you want to take it from 1pm to 2pm you can't? even though its still one hour?

Comment: What is allowed or not is probably less covered by Japanese law but your contract. What does your contract mention about the right o be late once per month?

Comment: The purpose of the rule is clearly to allow for occasional emergencies or tardiness while still ensuring that you get to work at a reasonable time (ie. well before 12PM) most days, not to let you make personal plans that stretch out to 1PM on a workday. The company doesn't care that you go to lunch, and that 12PM is both the cutoff time and lunchtime seems unrelated. Would the rule not be "abusive" if they made the threshold for being late 11AM instead?

Comment: @DarkCygnus It's a weird policy, I know. In simple terms, I can't attend my kid's AM school event (or I have to leave right in the middle of it), in order to fulfill the stupid requirement of heading over to the company and clock in by noon, only to not have that lunch break count toward my pay anyway. And if we are allowed to be somewhere else during lunch break, the place I want to be is at my kid's event. So making it mandatory to show up by noon only to not get paid, and still have it wreck my plans, is pretty awful.

Comment: @DarkCygnus To address your other comment: Yes, it is inflexible in that regard too. The lunch hour is a set time from 12:00PM to 1:00PM for everyone.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Well if the cutoff time were 11:00AM at least I would get paid for the hour from 11 to 12. And it wouldn't amount to be required to show up for unpaid time. There would at least be a purpose.

Comment: @Drudgery, I think your rationale is that, since the company effectively allows you to be absent all morning, why not go further and allow you to clock in after dinner? I think the company's rationale is probably that you're already taking things to the outer limit though, and should either be booking leave (if it's a one-off all-AM school event), or not expecting to attend the school at all. You seem to imply that it would be no loss to them to allow you to arrive at 1300, but it is a loss insofar as it encourages and allows people to take more whole mornings off work without booking leave.

Comment: Then just arrive at 11, you're not forced to be late. And take time off if you want to attend an event that's going until 1PM, whether it's a day or half a day. Clearly the intent of the rule is "you can occasionally be late and we won't ask whether it's an emergency or rectal myopia, so long as you clock in at some point before lunch", not for people to take a planned half a day off twice a month.

Comment: A company is well within their rights to define a policy surrounding what is considered an absence from work.  The fact this time is right before the designated lunchbreak likely isn't a violation of any worker laws.  If you need to attend a school event, in the morning, you likely should be taking leave.

Comment: What are you hoping for here? Let's assume for a moment this is illegal (it's not, by the way). So the company is made aware its policy is illegal. They then say "Ok all employees must be at their station ready to work by their contracted start time, no exceptions". This is certainly legal as it's how employment contracts have works for many decades. Would you consider this a preferable situation?

Answer (score 10):

I think the purpose of the policy is that "arriving late" or "leaving early" should consist of less than half a day of absence.

The policy is that someone wanting a full half-day of absence - and therefore not required to be present either before or after the dinner hour - should book it as leave.

The idea that you can clock in a minute before dinner, having skipped the entire morning session in substance, then proceed to take a whole hour of break, is probably considered the outer limit of the concession rather than the normal intended usage.

Given that the lateness is (presumably) unarranged and unrecorded beforehand, it also means that the employer knows by the start of the dinner hour (at the latest) whether you are present that day or AWOL.

Or if you "leave early" after the dinner hour, it still gives people a chance to catch you before you go (as opposed to your leaving at the beginning of the dinner hour, and not returning at all for the rest of the day).

Comment: I guess I should mention that tardiness that is announced prior to the day is treated the same *on record* as unannounced tardiness. The difference is that unannounced tardiness doesn't leave a very good impression.

Comment: @Drudgery, your company's policy seems to be that it isn't tardiness at all (provided it happens no more than twice a month), but a facility to arrive later than normal (which can be intentional, rather than accidental). As you say though, practically speaking, colleagues still want to know where others are and what their availability is. Is there any informal facility to take long dinners (as you might if you live close to home and are attending an appointment right in the middle of the day, say)?

Comment: Upvoted, but I think you mean lunch every time you wrote dinner in your answer. Noon to 1pm is usually the second meal of the day and that is usually called lunch.

Comment: @quarague, yes I'm using the dinner vs tea nomenclature, rather than lunch vs dinner!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know if something is legal, ask a labor lawyer practicing in your part of the world.

Personally, I think they are being extremely generous in allowing you a full morning off when you genuinely need one, and you are being unreasonable in complaining. Most companies would make you take a half day of vacation or sick time or unpaid leave, or tell you to make up the missing hours by working late or weekends or holidays.

Answer (score 1):

> The company allows employees to either arrive late or leave early twice per pay period month, without having to use paid leave time.

Let me summarize: Up to two times *less* than four hours of absence in the morning are accepted at your company.

Four hours or more of absence in the morning have to be taken as half a day off. It is unlucky that your interpretation of this generous rule seems to be to take it to the limit and then complain about a related issue.

If you regularly plan to be 4 hours absent in the morning I recommend that you find an explicit regulation about your work time with your company.